# Why I get NoSuchKey in DigitalOcean Buckets?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean-spaces

I am using DigitalOcean's spaces which in turn is S3 compatible. I created some buckets, I can WITHOUT any problem upload files with Python/aioboto3 using credentials, BUT, I just can't get a list of files contained in a bucket... here's the code in python:

```
async def list_files(bucket_name):
    session = aioboto3.Session()
    async with session.client(
        's3',
        region_name=config("S3REGION"),
        endpoint_url=config("S3URL"),
        aws_access_key_id=config("S3AK"),
        aws_secret_access_key=config("S3PK"),
        config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
    ) as s3_client:
        try:
            response = await s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)
            return response.get("Contents", [])
        except Exception as e:
            return "500 - " + str(e) + " // " + bucket_name
```

forget the return, the problem arises in the line:
response = await s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

which gives the error:
"500 - An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: Unknown // mybucketname"

TRUST that credentials are ok since the same are using for fileu ploading and they work. I tryed in aioboto3 docs, the whole internet and DigitalOcean's community which has an UNANSWERED same exact issue since 2021.

I'm new in the cloud and hope someone can give me an insight on what might be wrong.

Thanks is advance.

I've tryed uploading a file which works
I've tryed to retrieve the buckets which gives an empty array
I verifyed in DigitalOcean's spaces manages that all the names are correct
I verifyed that credentials work
I wrestled with chatgpt which proved useless
I looked to the poorly implemented aioboto3 documentation
I searched the new with no success
IDK what else to do

Comment: Can you list the contents of that bucket by using the AWS CLI (pointing to Digital Ocean)?

Comment: Possibly going to be the endpoint_url you're using. Does it include the bucket name? Remove it.

Comment: DO requires the use of `s3={'addressing_style': 'virtual'}` in the client config.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein as simple as your response is, interacting with the CLI immediately surfaced the error!!! Thank you, I will post the full fix...

Comment: @jarmod exactly! I was using the same URL that I used for uploading which in my case included the bucket... thanks. Will post the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my problem was that I was including my bucket's name in the URL that I was using. As you guys pointed out, I modified my code as follows:

```
async def list_files(bucket_name, prefix):
    session = aioboto3.Session()
    async with session.client(
        's3',
        region_name=config("S3REGION"),
        endpoint_url=config("S3URLCLEAN"), #This is the url WITHOUT my bucket
        aws_access_key_id=config("S3AK"),
        aws_secret_access_key=config("S3PK"),
        config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
    ) as s3_client:
        try:
            response = await s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix) #the prefix is 'myfoldername/'
            return response.get("Contents", [])
        except Exception as e:
            return "500 - " + str(e) + " // " + bucket_name
```

Obviously I will work the right error handlers and stuff, but for testing purposes, this works. Now I receive a JSON with all the files in my folder contained in the bucket!!!

Thanks a lot for the real quick help guys!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my hours <3